# How to print string that contains unicode symbols?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, printing

When I do `print(my_str)` output looks like this:

`name\u201d:\u201d\u041e\u043b\u0435\u0433\u201d`

How can I print my string like a Unicode string (where u\XXXX sentences replaced by symbols)?

IDK is it important or not but `my_str` comes from a file.

Comment: Try `print(my_str.decode("unicode-escape"))`.  This may fail if you're running the code in an environment that doesn't support Unicode output.

Comment: @jasonharper lol... 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. And `encode()` just replaces line breaks with `\n`.

Comment: Try opening the file with the `"unicode-escape"` encoding.

Comment: `bytes(my_str, encoding='utf8').decode('unicode-escape')` seems to work.

Comment: Or, as Daniel H said, better try to read the string correctly from the file in the first place.

Comment: Would that "file" be a JSON file?  Use the `json` module to read it.